# 5V bus and 12V bus from 40-58V battery

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, 12v, 5v, step-down

I have a lithium ion battery which operates between 40 and 58V along its discharge. I need a 5V bus to power a MCU and some sensors as well as a 12V one for lights, a horn, etc. Is there a better way to do this between stepping both of them down with different switching voltage regulators straight from the battery or stepping down to 12V and from this stepping down again to 5V?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If your need of 5V is only powering a MCU and other sensors (current rating is, say, 100mA max) then no need to use an SMPS for it. Just put an SMPS for battery-to-12V then put a simple 12V-to-5V linear regulator.

Comment: better that @RohatKılıç says, there are [drop-in switching replacements for the classic 78xx series regulators](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/non-isolated-dc-dc-converters/7962132/)

Comment: Since you'll certainly want to use a buck converter to get from your battery to 12 volts, what to do about getting the 5 volts is going to depend on how much current your 5 volt load needs.  Do you know how much that is?

Comment: It all depends on the current you'll draw from both rails, the efficiencies of the DC-DC converters you plan to use, and the complexity/cost you can tolerate (e.g. a 60V->5V DC-DC converter will be more complex/expensive than a 12V->5V linear regulator, as Rohat suggested - but if you need 3A on the 5V rail, this is really a bad idea). Since you didn't mention anything on these constraints, we can't tell you.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help! I would need a max of 2A-3A on the 5V bus to allow for a safety margin. Knowing that the system will draw around 1A

Comment: @ChrisH - Yes there are drop-in replacements, but at least the one linked will not work in the OPs application.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the one I linked was following on from Rohat Kılıç's comment about regulating down from 12V, which it should do (subject to min/max current requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you decide whether any strategy is "best", you have to define how better is measured.  Is the criterion cost, size, efficiency, long term availability of parts, has the right color, or something else?

For a reasonable electrical design tradeoff, you start with defining the maximum current each supply must be able to source, and what part of that must happen concurrently.

If the 5 V supply only needs to source a small fraction of the 12 V power, then it's probably better to deal with the high and variable voltage once to make 12 V, then make 5 V from there.

If the 5 V current requirement is really low, like only running a small microcontroller, then just a linear regulator might be good enough to go from 12 V to 5 V.  For example, if the maximum 5 V current is 60 mA, then a linear regulator would only dissipate 420 mW.  A 7805 in TO-220 package sticking up in free air can handle that in many circumstances.  You can put a resistor on the input of the 7805 that drops its input down to 7.5 V at maximum current.  Then the 7805 only dissipates 150 mW, and the resistor does the remaining 270 mW.

If the 5 V supply has to source more power, then use a buck regulator from 12 V to 5 V.  If the 5 V supply must source a "large" amount of power relative to the 12 supply, then a separate buck from the battery may make more sense, especially if efficiency is important.

There are lots of options.  Again, you have to start with real specs, then define how "best" is to be measured.